# Find BoundField value from parent gridview on OnRowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a parent and child gridview setup. on the OnRowDataBound event I need the value of a parent gridview cell. this is not the DataKeys of the parent Gridview. I have commented out some of the things I have tried, but not getting quite there. I think the last two lines are close, but I am not sure what the correct syntax should be.

gvCustomers is the parentGV.

```
  {
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
  string requestId = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
  gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select top 10 * from Orders where RequestID='{0}'", requestId));
  gvOrders.DataBind(); // this is the childGV

  string cell_1_Value = gvCustomers.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
  string cell_2_Value = gvCustomers.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
  }
  }
```

This is now working using:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvCustomers.Rows)
    {
        string requestStatus = gvCustomers.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
    }
```

But is there anyway to get the same value using the name of the column?

Comment: Which cell or column are you trying to get (name or position)?

Comment: I have managed to do it using this,  foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvCustomers.Rows)
            { string requestStatus = gvCustomers.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text; }   .  So it is Cell[3] I need to read. But Ideally, I would like to read using column header, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
      string requestId = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
      GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
      gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select top 10 * from Orders where RequestID='{0}'", requestId));
      gvOrders.DataBind(); // this is the childGV

      System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
      string requestStatus = dr["myColumnHeader"].ToString();
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Would you mind explaining how "System.Data.DataRowView" actually works?

Comment: What I can say is that once you re-initialize the generic data item as specific type (DataRow) this allows you to navigate the item's Properties more "specifically". If this is not a satisfactory enough explanation then take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx.  Regards!